# GitLab PHP docker image - the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system

Tags: php, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm writing some unit tests for our application and we're using GitLab CI with GitLab Runner v11.11.1 and using Docker executor with image php:7.1.

When running `composer install` (our composer version is 1.10.17) I get the following error on a few required packages:

> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system

I've tried a couple things like on our `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```sh
apt-get update -yqq
apt-get install -yqq libpng-dev
```

But that also produced the same error.

I also tried requiring `ext-gd` from the `composer.json` file:

```sh
composer require ext-gd
```

But I got this error:

> The requested PHP extension ext-gd ^7.1 is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.

The last attempt I made was:

```sh
apt-get install php-common
phpenmod gd
```

But this gave me this error:

> Unable to locate package php-common

---

Does anyone know how to simply enable the PHP extension gd so I can run my unit tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the errors when I added this to my `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
...
before_script:
  - apt-get update -yqq
  - apt-get install libjpeg-dev libpng-dev -yqq
  - docker-php-ext-install gd
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need PHP GD library. For Debian and Debian based systems, e.g. Ubuntu, as well as Debian based Docker containers use:

```
apt-get install -qy php-gd
```

If it's still unclear, or you have older/other system just search

```
apt-cache search php gd
```

and will find out possible package candidates.

For Docker containers it seems you need a different route, so Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache-buster
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -qqy
RUN php -v
RUN apt-get install -qy libpng-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

Comment: This gave me this error: Package php-gd is a virtual package provided by:
  php7.3-gd 7.3.19-1~deb10u1 [Not candidate version]
E: Package 'php-gd' has no installation candidate

Comment: please use appropriate php version for you. I will amend answer

Comment: also very strange that you use php7.1 container image, but get 7.3 version in packages, but just use one matching your build.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php7.1-gd
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-gd'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-gd'

Comment: Added Docker specific solution